# Ajax call not done after a click on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, jquery-ui, spring-mvc

When a user click on a button, i display a dialog box to confirm it action and after i do a delete on the server

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/secure/admin/deleteuser/{username}")
public String deleteUser(Model model, @PathVariable("username") String username, BindingResult result) {
...
}

$("#deleteUserConfirm").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        height: 180,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Delete user": function() {
                var username = $(this).data('username');
                var url = "/secure/admin/deleteuser/" + username;

                //server call to delete this user
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: url
                }).done(function() {
                    alert("second success");
                }).fail(function() {
                   alert("error");
                }).always(function() {
                   alert("finished");
                });

                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
```

i never go to the server... i see second success alert and finished alert
i don't have any error

i tried on the server

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/secure/admin/deleteuser")
public String deleteUser(Model model, @RequestParam("username") String username, BindingResult result) {
```

}

in js

```
                 $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/secure/admin/deleteuser",
                    data: {username: "RenewalRate2"}
                }).done(function() {
                    alert("second success");
                }).fail(function() {
                   alert("error");
                }).always(function() {
                   alert("finished");
                });
```

i see in chrome a  request to:

```
`http://localhost:8084/secure/admin/deleteuser?username=RenewalRate2`
```

in it's status it's 200... but nothing is done on the server.....

Comment: If success and done alerts are happening, it's definitely getting to the server because the server returned a 200 statusCode.

Comment: the problem can be that dialog never closed?

Comment: What is the ajax request response code?

Comment: code 200, i put a system out on the server and it never go there...

Answer (score 0):

It might be a case of browser caching. Firefox might be showing status as 200 but request nevergets out of browser, try to append a dummy parameter at the end and then see the results.

Answer (score 0):

Use confirm dialog.

```
var status = confirm("Are you sure??");
if(status == true)
{
   //Make an ajax call and delete
}
else
{
  //Do nothing.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i changed controller for

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/secure/admin/deleteuser")
@ResponseBody
public void deleteUser(@RequestParam("username") String userName) {
}
```

and that work file